# Idiom opposite to "the straw that broke the camel's back"

Tags: idiom-requests

In my native language, we say something like:

> No matter how full the bag, a grain still fits.

Example:

- Person A: I know we are close to the page limit, but can we still fit this sentence in the article?
- Person B: No matter how full the bag, a grain still fits.

**Is there an equivalent idiom in English?**

Comment: **"There's always room for a/another/one more _______"** The blank is filled by the previously mentioned noun.

Comment: "You can't have too much of a good thing" is a relevant general saying.

Comment: The idiom is certainly not the opposite of (not "to") last straw, which does not mean tha the bag is full.

Comment: If it's ice cream, then a common saying is "there's always room for ice cream". (It's been really hot here the last few days, so of course that's where my head went . . .)

Comment: 'Room for a little one' / 'There's always room for a little one' is a common variant on Greybeard's suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's always room for one more.

This has been the title of a number of books and movies, but it seems to have been an idiom first. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=always+room+for+one+more+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calways%20room%20for%20one%20more%3B%2Cc0).